# Aplicar una clase de bootstrap dependiendo del tamaño de la pantalla

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en angular en el cual en un componente estoy haciendo una fila de imagenes, el resultado que espero es que tengan poca opacidad cuando se vean en pantallas grande pero cuando se vean en una pantalla chica (menos que md) la opacidad sea del 100%
este es mi codigo html

```
<div class="proyects">
        <div *ngFor="let pro of proyect">
            <a [href]="pro.linkProyect" ><img [src]="pro.imgProyect "  class="imgproyect" [alt]="pro.nombreProyect"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

y este mi codigo css

```
.proyects{
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
width: 100%;
overflow-x: auto;
overflow-y: hidden;
height: 25%;}

.imgproyect{
 border-radius: 10px;
 margin:0 5px 2px 0;
 transition-duration: 1.1s;
 }
```

Comment: Lecturas recomendadas:  [media-queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) y revisa [los tamaños que usa bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/grid/#grid-options) para establecerlos de forma similar en tus media-queries según lo que pretendas.

Comment: Esto en angular (cosa que no te recomiendo) se resuelve con `@HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])`, yo personalmente usaria css por que no necesitas meterte en el tema de componentes.

Answer (score 0):

Con media-queries puedes hacerlo

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .imgproyect {
        //OPACIDAD QUE DESEES
    }
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .imgproyect {
        //OPACIDAD QUE DESEES
    }
}
```